# Check whether a number is Prime number using Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I know there are already many codes available on this topic, but somehow my code just won't give me the right answer for number 27 and I rlly want to know what I did wrong. See my code below. Thank you.

Assume numbers are positive integers.

```
def isPrime(x):
    """Returns whether or not the given number x is prime.

    A prime number is a natural number greater than 1 that cannot be formed
    by multiplying two smaller natural numbers.

    For example:
    - Calling isPrime(11) will return True
    - Calling isPrime(71) will return True
    - Calling isPrime(12) will return False
    - Calling isPrime(76) will return False
    """
    
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    if x ==1:
        return False
    if x ==2:
        return True
    for a in range(2,x):
        if x %a ==0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Below is the error message when I test the code:

[image]

Comment: What happens when `a` is `3` in the loop?

Comment: a never gets to 3

Answer (score 1):

the error in the code is that the function prematurely returns True as soon as it finds the first number that doesn't divide x without leaving a remainder. It does not check all the possible divisors before making a final decision.

```
def isPrime(x):
    """Returns whether or not the given number x is prime.

    A prime number is a natural number greater than 1 that cannot be formed
    by multiplying two smaller natural numbers.

    For example:
    - Calling isPrime(11) will return True
    - Calling isPrime(71) will return True
    - Calling isPrime(12) will return False
    - Calling isPrime(76) will return False
    """
    
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    if x ==1:
        return False
    if x ==2:
        return True
    for a in range(2,x):
        if x %a ==0:
            return False
    return True
```

Please note that you return true with the else part. it should run entire numbers and after that only it should return true. This way, the loop will check all possible divisors before determining whether the number is prime or not

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x==1):
    return False
elif (x==2):
    return True
else:
    for i in range(2,x):
        if (x % i==0):
                return False
    return True
```

print(isPrime(11))

#output True

Comment: `print(isPrime(11))`—where is `isPrime()` defined? Did you mean to put the first code block inside a function?